# ¿como seleccionar multiples fechas en un mismo campo usando Datepicker 1.9.0?

Tags: html, jquery, datepicker

estoy usando Datepicker 1.9.0, para seleccion de fechas desde un campo de tipo calendario.

necesito saber como puedo seleccionar multiples fechas en el mismo campo:

que en el mismo campo el usuario pueda eligir varias fechas como en el siguiente ejemplo:

11/10/2020

12/10/2020

13/10/2020

todas esas fechas en el mismo campo y separarlas ya sea por espacio o por -.

> todas esas fechas en el mismo campo y separarlas ya sea por espacio o
> por -.

agrego caso de prueba, donde inluyo todos los archivos que estoy utilizando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$('.registerFormFcMv').bootstrapValidator({
    live: 'enabled',
    fields: {
        newinputTratFechaIni: {
            validators: {
                date: {
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    message: 'ESTE VALOR NO COINCIDE CON UNA FECHA'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 10,
                    message: 'LA LONGITUD MÁXIMA ES DE 10 INCLUYENDO /'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[0-9-/]+$/,
                    message: 'LA FECHA SOLO PUEDE TENER NÚMEROS Y /'
                }
            }
        }

    }
});

$('.datepicker3').datepicker({

    container: '.container-calendar',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    language: 'es'

});
```

```html
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--****************************************************
                MODAL REGISTRAR DAT
********************************************************-->
<!--VALIDAR DATOS -->
<div id="modalAgregarFcMv" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <form class="form registerFormFcMv" role="form" method="post" id="form-create-fcmv" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <!--****************************************************
                CABEZA MODAL
                ********************************************************-->

                <div class="modal-header" style="background: #444444b4; color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">

                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> REGISTRAR FC-MV 001</h4>

                </div>

                <!--****************************************************
                CUERPO DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="box-body">

                        <!--TRATAMIENTO FECHA DE INICIO-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer ">
                            <label class="control-label" for="text">TRATAMIENTO FECHA DE INICIO:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg date datepicker3 container-calendar" id="newTratFechaInii">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control puntero-i prohibido-no" name="newinputTratFechaIni" id="newTratFechaIni" value="" placeholder="CLIC AQUÍ Ó EN EL ICONO" required>
                                <span class="input-group-addon manito-clic ">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--****************************************************
                PIE DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="registrar-Fcmv">
                    <button type="button" class="btn pull-left manito-clic" id="salir-antem" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manito-clic submit-fcmv" disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"
></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/language/es_ES.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El **datepicker** de **Bootstrap** al inicializarse puede definirse el atributo `multidate` con valor a `true` para permitir la selección de múltiples fechas.

```js
$('.registerFormFcMv').bootstrapValidator({
    live: 'enabled',
    fields: {
        newinputTratFechaIni: {
            validators: {
                date: {
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                    message: 'ESTE VALOR NO COINCIDE CON UNA FECHA'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 10,
                    max: 10,
                    message: 'LA LONGITUD MÁXIMA ES DE 10 INCLUYENDO /'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[0-9-/]+$/,
                    message: 'LA FECHA SOLO PUEDE TENER NÚMEROS Y /'
                }
            }
        }

    }
});

$('.datepicker3').datepicker({
    container: '.container-calendar',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    language: 'es',
    multidate: true
});
```

```html
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--****************************************************
                MODAL REGISTRAR DAT
********************************************************-->
<!--VALIDAR DATOS -->
<div id="modalAgregarFcMv" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <form class="form registerFormFcMv" role="form" method="post" id="form-create-fcmv" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <!--****************************************************
                CABEZA MODAL
                ********************************************************-->

                <div class="modal-header" style="background: #444444b4; color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">

                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> REGISTRAR FC-MV 001</h4>

                </div>

                <!--****************************************************
                CUERPO DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="box-body">

                        <!--TRATAMIENTO FECHA DE INICIO-->
                        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer ">
                            <label class="control-label" for="text">TRATAMIENTO FECHA DE INICIO:</label>
                            <div class="input-group input-group-lg date datepicker3 container-calendar" id="newTratFechaInii">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control puntero-i prohibido-no" name="newinputTratFechaIni" id="newTratFechaIni" value="" placeholder="CLIC AQUÍ Ó EN EL ICONO" required>
                                <span class="input-group-addon manito-clic ">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!--****************************************************
                PIE DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="registrar-Fcmv">
                    <button type="button" class="btn pull-left manito-clic" id="salir-antem" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary manito-clic submit-fcmv" disabled>REGISTRAR</button>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"
></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/language/es_ES.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: gracias bro, otra pregunta como ves estoy usando boostraValidator para validar mis inputs, hay alguna forma de validar multiples fechas usando ese plugins? es decir que si hay más de una fecha me permita validarla?

Comment: Me temo que eso ya excede el alcance de la pregunta inicial. Te recomiendo que formules una nueva pregunta en el sitio con los problemas que tengas respecto a esa validación de fechas que comentas ^^